# Can i have a tabs under collapse toolbar in android?

Tags: android, material-design

currently i wish to do a screen which have collapse toolbar and a tab under it.
I able to come the collapse toolbar and tab, but the content of the tab doesn't show out.

So i want ask whether i can put the tabs under collapse toolbar? If yes, anyone can teach? TQ.

Below is the screen layout that i manage to do.

[image]

Comment: You just wanna to that like above screenshot?

Comment: ya, and the tab able to swipe

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <com.thelittlenaruto.supportdesignexample.customview.MyNestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <com.thelittlenaruto.supportdesignexample.customview.WrapContentHeightViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </com.thelittlenaruto.supportdesignexample.customview.MyNestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:background="@color/deep_green_700_alpha_50"
                android:minHeight="190dp"
                android:src="@drawable/naruto_hinata"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Taken from:** https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample

Comment: Tq, i will try it ^^

Comment: yw, remember, that sample is using customviews, do not forget to add them: https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/thelittlenaruto/supportdesignexample/customview i've tried that without these customviews and that has a problem btw,goodluck!